# Group By using Timestamp in Django Queryset

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have one model where each entry is stored and its created time is stored. The time is not a **datetime** object a **timestamp**. Timestamp field of model is shown below :

> logged_at = models.CharField(_('log time'), max_length=128,
>   default=time.time)

If above field is datetime field then I can write an query which can group by records using datetime field like :

```
MyModel.objects.filter(type_='in').annotate(in_time=RawSQL('(date(logged_at))', [])).values('in_time', 'name').annotate(count=Count('name'))
```

But I am not able to query the timesatmp field in same way , It gives me the error `date/time field value out of range`

I have also tried to use functions like `to_timestamp` nut still no success

```
MyModel.objects.filter(type_='in').annotate(in_time=RawSQL('(date(to_timestamp(logged_at)))', [])).values('in_time', 'name').annotate(count=Count('name'))
```

**Error :**  function to_timestamp(character varying) does not exist

Database I am using is **Postgres**

Comment: Well that means that some of the columns contain some "timestamp" data that is apparently out of range (so a month that is too large, etc.). This is why you should not use `CharField`s to store time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  I have posted the answer to my question, I have changed the type of timestamp field at runtime to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Willem mentioned in comment that timestamp must not be stored in `CharField`. So We can try to change type of field at runtime like given below.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(type_='in').annotate(in_time=RawSQL('(date(to_timestamp(logged_at::float)))', [])).values('in_time', 'name').annotate(count=Count('name'))
```

IN above query I have changed type of `logged_at` to `float` and it works fine for me, you can also change it to `int`.